# how to call a c# webmethod on mouseover of linkbutton in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0, asmx

Is it possible to call a c# webmethod on mouseover on Linkbutton ? what i want is to call a webmethod in which i am binding a repeater control with datatable. How? 
in aspx:

```
<asp:LinkButton Text='<%#Eval("SNA")%>' ID="lnkpro1" runat="server" 
CssClass="linkbutton" servicemethod="GetRecords" 
OnClick="btn_Click1" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Sets") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

in aspx.cs:

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public void GetRecords(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

I am not getting the point that is how is it possible to call a webmethod on linkbutton mouseover. I have used a webmethod in  textbox autocomplete extender but it has a propperty of calling a webmethod but is it so in this case also? Thank you.

Comment: don't u need a mouseover javascript in your link button

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods, like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<Record> GetRecords()
{
    // Go to database to get list of records
    List<Record> listOfRecords = GetRecordsFromDatabase();

    return listOfRecords;
}
```

I made up the `Record` class here. A list of something needs to be returned, so I made it up for the example's sake.

---

> Note: ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods automatically JSON-encode their response, so there is no need for serialization in the page method if you are using JSON on the client-side.

---

Now you can call the ASP.NET AJAX Page Method, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.linkbutton').mouseover(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "PageName.aspx/GetRecords",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result) {
                // Do something with records returned here
                // Use result.d to get to JSON data
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you once again but how this will be called on linkbutton onmouseover.

Comment: @R_sharma - updated answer to use jQuery `mouseover()` function instead of `click()`.

Comment: hi karl can i get linkbutton id (not value :) ) not using c# which you told me yesterday but using javascript. Is it possible. Pleasy reply. Thank you.

Comment: @R_sharma - not sure I understand what you are asking. I would recommend asking a new question that explains what you mean by `can i get linkbutton id (not value)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using jQuery `Ajax` method to call a WebMethod:

[Refer this for an ultimate example for Calling an ASP.NET C# WebMethod](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/63e78b/call-an-Asp-Net-C-Sharp-method-web-method-using-jquery/)